# config.json - Adding database connection strings in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am in the process of learning ASP.NET vNext. I need to store two connection strings in the config.json file. How do I store those? Can I do this:

**config.json**

```
{
  "connectionStrings" : {
    "connection-1" : "server=...",
    "connection-2" : "server=..."
  }
}
```

I have not been able to find a schema for `config.json`. For that reason, I wasn't sure how to do it.  I saw the use of `IConfiguration` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs). Still, I wasn't sure how `Configuration` was available in the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/configuration) is the official Configuration repo and [this](http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/) is a great blog post explaining the configuration system.

Long story short:

1. [You need one or more `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.*` NuGet packages in your application](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/project.json#L26). The list of available packages is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/tree/dev/src).
2. [Add the configuration sources that you need](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L20-L22)
3. [Build the config file(s)](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/config.json)
4. [Read the configuration sources](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L48)

Comment: Thank you for sharing. How would you use this model on a class library though? From what I can see, I would have to re-instantiate an `IConfiguration` object in every single instance of a class in my class library. This seems inefficient. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can inject `IConfiguration` or even hold a static reference to it somewhere...

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Do you know of an example of IConfiguration getting injected? I'm slowly learning this stuff :)

Comment: I wrote this article a while ago and except a few packages being renamed, it should be a good place to start with dependency injection in ASP.NET vNext http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

```
 {   
      "Data": {
        "connection-1": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=..."
        },
        "connection-2": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=..."
        }   
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done these days...

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDb1": "Server=myServer;Database=myDb1;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "myDb2": "Server=myServer;Database=myDb2;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

From: [Store and read connection string in appsettings.json](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-and-read-connection-string-in-appsettings-json/)