# How do I point to my full SQL Server Express database in ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

**Context**

I have an existing project which is a data access layer that connects to a local SQL Server Express 12 database.

I now want to create a new ASP.NET Core project in the same solution which utilises this database.  I also want to use the baked in user authentication with the relevant tables being added to this database.

**What I've done**

I've created the ASP.NET Core project successfully but it points to a newly created (localdb)MSSQLLocalDB rather than my SQL Server Express database.  I changed the connection string in appsettings.json to:

```
"DefaultConnection": {
  "ConnectionString": "Server=MAIN-DESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ArbitrageSearch;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

I expected it to then complain about missing tables but actually the application continues to access (localdb)MSSQLLocalDB.

**Question**

How do I point to my existing SQL Express database and then how do I initialise the tables necessary to support user authentication?

Comment: take a look at [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) how to configure this in App.Config file ..

Comment: If the core application and express database are on the server you should simply do: `.\SQLExpress` it will automatically target the localhost.

Comment: @MethodMan Asp.Net Core doesn't have an `app.config` it has an `appsettings.json`, he is correct.

Comment: I would have him look at this Nuget Package then if my understanding is correct.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849370/config-json-adding-database-connection-strings-in-asp-net-vnext reference the answer here

Comment: Seems to work with that change and the relevant tables have appeared @Greg .  Happy to mark as answered if you'll do the necessary.

Comment: @ifinlay Converted to an answer, happy it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the Core Application and SQL Express database are on the same server, you'll want to change the Connection String to: `.\SQLExpress`.  This will automatically target the localhost.

Which will indicate the Express SQL Instance.

Answer (score 4):

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=netCore.Project;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"  
},
```

Note that // is required. After that `update-database` PM console

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me to do was in Visual Studio to show SQL Server Object Explorer, possibly add the server to the list, right click on the desired database, select "Properties" copy the property "Connection String" and use that in the appsettings.json file.